# Firebase database writes get errors once in a while (python)

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I use the [firebase-admin-python](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python) library to create and update firebase entities realtime database from python process. once in a while I get this errors:

```
api call error (('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')))
```

I will be happy to know if anyone else gets that error too and what is the reason for that error to occur?

OS version: Ubuntu 16.04,
Python: 3.4,
firebase-admin-python: 2.4
firebase product: database

Comment: Connection resets are expected while the client is connecting to the server. They are also quite common if the client stays connected for any reasonable amount of time. Unless you're having functional problems with the code, I wouldn't worry about the messages.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. Not sure about functional problems, just wanted to know if this kind of errors are common and "known".